# Поворачивать объект каждые 5 секунд

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

на окне есть объект. Мне нужно чтобы после запуска окна через 5 секунд этот объект провернулся на 360 градусов, подождал опять 5 секунд, повернулся и так постоянно.
Вот что смог написать:

```
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="27" Margin="35,14,835,553" StrokeThickness="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="30" RenderTransformOrigin="0.529,0.481">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="bla.png"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="rotate"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <Rectangle.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotate"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:1">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Oscillations="0"></ElasticEase>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
```

Здесь объект просто при запуске окна проворачивается 1 раз. Мне нужно чтобы он проворачивался каждые 5 секунд, а при запуске поворачивался не сразу, а через 5 секунд.

Comment: Вот и отлично. В будущем не забывайте таким образом благодарить тех, кто помог вам (: Комментарии не по делу я сейчас удалю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы сделать задержку у DoubleAnimation либо Storyboard, необходимо использовать свойство BeginTime. Для того, чтобы сделать повторение анимации, необходимо использовать свойство Repeat.
В вашем случае код такой

```
<Storyboard Duration="0:0:6" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
     From="0" To="360" BeginTime="0:0:5" Duration="0:0:1">
    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Oscillations="0"></ElasticEase>
    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
  </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

здесь

```
RepeatBehavior="Forever"
```

используется для того, чтобы анимация происходила бесконечно. Если вам нужно повторять определенное число раз, тогда задайте

```
RepeatBehavior="2x"
```

для этого кода анимация будет повторяться 2 раза. Если вам нужно повторять определенное время, тогда задайте

```
RepeatBehavior="0:0:10"
```

где анимация будет повторяться 10 секунд

Comment: спасибо, он крутится бесконечно, что мне и надо, но перед каждым вращением мне нужно чтобы он не крутился 5 секунд

Comment: @КозявкаДедаМороза вы можете задать Duration и RepeatBehavior у Storyboard. я обновлю свой ответ.

Comment: @КозявкаДедаМороза думаю, в этом случае RepeatBehavior="Forever" у DoubleAnimation вам не нужен, т.к. продолжительность Storyboard ограничит количество повторений DoubleAnimation до одного, а повторяться бесконечно будет сам Storyboard.

Comment: спасибо большое